# Cheese with vaapi

Tags: 10.10, cheese, gma500

I am using a Dell Inspiron Mini 10 with GMA500 video drivers. GMA500 fixes resolution issues and enables video acceleration. The only problem with the GMA500 drivers I am having is that I can not find a fix for the webcam program called cheese, and I can't find a way to enable the vaapi (Video Acceleration API) backend. Videos don't work with the GMA500 (without vaapi) and I cannot properly use cheese.

If anyone can help me out with this I will be grateful because Google isn't helping me much with this problem.

Comment: it didnt work with cheese after it worked when i tested it
What else can i do to make cheese work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GMA 500 'Poulsbo' has had a history of difficulties. However I found a guide on the Ubuntu Forums that describes itself as the *[Guide to Get the Best Performace from the GMA 500](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1229345)*. The forum thread has over 2.5k posts.

Whilst I'm not sure if this will get Cheese working, this seems to me the best thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but maybe testing with `gstreamer-properties` will lead you somewhere.  Cheese just uses gstreamer, so if you can get it working in `gstreamer-properties` then it will work in cheese.